# Ionic with Angular: Can't import the named export from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I've come across several solutions to the above error, but none relating to Ionic, which makes solving it really difficult for me.

The error comes up when I use the Angular component `ng-recaptcha` on my Ionic 6 project. Immediately the component is imported, the error gets thrown. Several solutions related to `webpack` have been tried, including editing the `webpack.config.js` file, moving the file to the root of the project, but none of them solves my problem.

I'm using Ionic 6 with Angular 10